# How do I remove all remote git branches

Tags: git, branch, git-fetch

I want to remove locally all branches that I can see with `git branch -r`. I've already removed all files from .git/refs/remote/*/ and appropriate records from .git/info/refs, but they are still there.

Comment: Checked `.git/packed-refs`?

Comment: Not yet. Is it safe to edit this file manually?

Comment: Yeah, you can edit it manually (it's a simple text file with one or two lines for each ref), or call `git branch -r -D NAME`. Why do you want to delete them manually? - if those are deleted remotely you xan use `git fetch REMOTE --prune`

Comment: I can see this is a plain text file, I'm just afraid this can break the repository somehow :) What about `git branch -D`, how do I remove the reference to a remote branch with this command, for example `refs/remotes/origin/develop`?

Comment: They are not deleted remotely, and I don't want to delete them remotely. I just want to cleanup my local tree view from those remote branches :)

Comment: So `git branch -r -D name` should do the trick, right?

Answer (score 3):

This command did the job:

`git branch -r | xargs git branch -r -D`

From the [manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html):

> Use -r together with -d to delete remote-tracking branches. Note, that it only makes sense to delete remote-tracking branches if they no longer exist in the remote repository or if git fetch was configured not to fetch them again. See also the prune subcommand of git-remote(1) for a way to clean up all obsolete remote-tracking branches.

Thanks to @MrTux